# How to iterate over an asynchronous iterator with a timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I think it's easier to understand in terms of code:

```
try:
    async for item in timeout(something(), timeout=60):
        await do_something_useful(item)
except asyncio.futures.TimeoutError:
    await refresh()
```

I want the `async for` to run at most 60 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncTimedIterable` could be the implementation of `timeout()` in your code:

```
class _AsyncTimedIterator:

    __slots__ = ('_iterator', '_timeout', '_sentinel')

    def __init__(self, iterable, timeout, sentinel):
        self._iterator = iterable.__aiter__()
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._sentinel = sentinel

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            return await asyncio.wait_for(self._iterator.__anext__(), self._timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return self._sentinel


class AsyncTimedIterable:

    __slots__ = ('_factory', )

    def __init__(self, iterable, timeout=None, sentinel=None):
        self._factory = lambda: _AsyncTimedIterator(iterable, timeout, sentinel)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self._factory()
```

---

(original answer)

Or use this class to replace your `timeout()` function:

```
class AsyncTimedIterable:
    def __init__(self, iterable, timeout=None, sentinel=None):
        class AsyncTimedIterator:
            def __init__(self):
                self._iterator = iterable.__aiter__()

            async def __anext__(self):
                try:
                    return await asyncio.wait_for(self._iterator.__anext__(),
                                                  timeout)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    return sentinel

        self._factory = AsyncTimedIterator

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self._factory()
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if it didn't create a new class for each `AsyncTimedIterable` instance. (Defining a new class is a potentially heavy weight operation.) You could define an `_AsyncTimedIterator` as a separate class, and construct it in `AsyncTimedIterable.__init__`, passing `iterable` and `timeout` to `_AsyncTimedIterator` constructor.

Comment: This answer looks the most like what I wanted to achieve. Maybe my question is poorly phrased, in the sense that I need the async **iteration** to take at most TIMEOUT seconds. In the code you provide, it seems like every step of the iteration can take at most TIMEOUT seconds. I will update the question.

Comment: I updated the question. It seems to me `__anext__` must track the overall progress and decrement `self._timeout` accordingly. Also, it must raise `TimeoutError`.

Comment: Anyway, I mark you answer as the good one, because you solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is eating up elements of the original sequence, isn't it? When there is a time-out the next element of the original sequence is thrown away, I suspect?! I guess the proper way to do it is shown by the answer of ttyridal.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do something like this to create a websocket(also an async iterator) which times out if it doesn't get a message after a certain duration. I settled on the following:

```
socket_iter = socket.__aiter__()
try:
    while True:
        message = await asyncio.wait_for(
            socket_iter.__anext__(),
            timeout=10
        )
except asyncio.futures.TimeoutError:
    # streaming is completed
    pass
```

Comment: I think it's more appropriate, if you want to yield from the generator repeatedly, to call `__aiter__()` once, and then repeat calls to `__anext__()`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to use an `asyncio.Queue`, and separate the code into two coroutines:

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()
async for item in something():
    await queue.put(item)
```

In another coroutine:

```
while True:
    try:
        item = await asyncio.wait_for(queue.get(), 60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        if item is None:
            break  # use None or whatever suits you to gracefully exit
        await do_something_useful(item)
    refresh()
```

Please note, it will make the queue grow if the handler `do_something_useful()` is slower than `something()` generates items. You may set a `maxsize` on the queue to limit the buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is missing a couple of details, but assuming `something()` is an async iterator or generator and you want `item` to be `sentinel` everytime `something` has not yielded a value within the timeout, here is an implementation of `timeout()`:

```
import asyncio
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')

# async generator, needs python 3.6
async def timeout(it: AsyncIterator[T], timeo: float, sentinel: T) -> AsyncGenerator[T, None]:
    try:
        nxt = asyncio.ensure_future(it.__anext__())
        while True:
            try:
                yield await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(nxt), timeo)
                nxt = asyncio.ensure_future(it.__anext__())
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                yield sentinel
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        pass
    finally:
        nxt.cancel()  # in case we're getting cancelled our self
```

test:

```
async def something():
    yield 1
    await asyncio.sleep(1.1)
    yield 2
    await asyncio.sleep(2.1)
    yield 3


async def test():
    expect = [1, None, 2, None, None, 3]
    async for item in timeout(something(), 1, None):
        print("Check", item)
        assert item == expect.pop(0)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

When `wait_for()` times out it will cancel the task. Therefore, we need to wrap `it.__anext__()` in a task and then shield it, to be able to resume the iterator.

Comment: why are you actually using `asyncio.shield` on nxt? Is there any particular / fundamental reason?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: It is to avoid cancellation of the task fut, which is the default behavior of wait_for. If one does not want the future to be cancelled on timeout it must be guarded with `shield` (This is right from the docs of `wait_for`). Clearly we do not want cancellation, because we want to still wait on future to complete even after the first time-out happend.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question can be different based on nature of `refresh` function. If it's very short-running function it can be freely called inside coroutine. But if it's blocking function (due to network or CPU) it should be ran [in executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor) to avoid freezing asyncio event loop.

Code below shows example for the first case, changing it to run `refresh` in executor is not hard.

Second thing to be clarified is a nature of asynchronous iterator. As far as I understand, you're using it to either get result from `something` or `None` if timeout occurred.

If I understand logic correctly, your code can be written clearer (similar to non-async style as `asyncio` is created to allow) using [async_timeout](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout#async-timeout) context manager and without using asynchronous iterator at all:

```
import asyncio
from async_timeout import timeout


async def main():
    while True:
        try:
            async with timeout(60):
                res = await something()
                await do_something_useful(item)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
        finally:
            refresh()
```

Comment: `refresh` is actually a coroutine. Does it change something to your answer. I willing to accept https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245879/140837

Comment: @amirouche if refresh is a coroutine, you should await for it - `await refresh()`. Nothing more in answer should be changed.

Comment: The question uses `async for` to retrieve items to process, and the async iterator's `__anext__` must also be covered by the timeout. As far as I can tell, this requires a different approach, e.g. avoiding `async for` altogether and invoking `__anext__` manually (under async timeout). Other answers provide alternative solutions, such as [wrapping the async iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245879/1600898) and [uncoupling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245716/1600898) the timeout from the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the coroutine to execute `refresh` at least every 60 seconds.

If you need to execute `refresh` every 60 seconds regardless of what happens with `do_something_useful`, you can arrange that with a separate coroutine:

```
import time

async def my_loop():
    # ensure refresh() is invoked at least once in 60 seconds
    done = False
    async def repeat_refresh():
        last_run = time.time()
        while not done:
            await refresh()
            now = time.time()
            await asyncio.sleep(max(60 - (now - last_run), 0))
            last_run = now
    # start repeat_refresh "in the background"
    refresh_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(repeat_refresh())

    try:
        async for item in something():
            if item is not None:
                await do_something_useful(item)
            await refresh()
    finally:
        done = True
```

Comment: I could do that, but it requires some synchronization between both coroutines. What `refresh` does is refresh the TTL of distributed lock. So, I want the refresh to stop if something bad happens to the "main" coroutine.

Comment: @amirouche If by "something bad" you mean an exception, that is easily arranged - I've now amended the code to use `finally` to terminate `repeat_refresh` in case of an exception in `my_loop()`.

Comment: Sorry, I find that solution less readable than https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245879/140837

Comment: @amirouche Hey, no problem :) just offering an alternative. Having a coroutine that does its thing independently is much more robust in my book, but tastes vary.