# Is there a way to access MQTT messages in Python as a generator/iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, mqtt, yield

Currently I need to write a python script, which should analyze some data provided via MQTT. The method I have to use for this needs a generator/iterator as a parameter. Sadly it seems like the paho-mqtt lib in python can access the messages only via the on_message callback method and just putting a 'yield' in that callback shouldn't work. Is there a way to access the published messages as a generator or is there a possibility to put them into one (maybe via multithreading) or is there maybe another package I could use for this? I am not that familiar with python and I couldn't find a solution.
Hope someone has an idea.
Cheers
Niklas

Comment: @eyllanesc because the library I need to use for the analyzing expects the generator as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile there is such a library: [asyncio-mqtt](https://github.com/sbtinstruments/asyncio-mqtt)

It is a wrapper around `paho-mqtt` that build on top of standard asyncio.

The nice thing is that it provides a contextmanager/generator interface for subscribing and reading messages which it makes it really convenient to work with. No more callbacks. From the docs

```
async with Client("test.mosquitto.org") as client:
    async with client.filtered_messages("floors/+/humidity") as messages:
        await client.subscribe("floors/#")
        async for message in messages:
            print(message.payload.decode())
```

Nice is also that it can be combined with other async code to add features. For instance a [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778254/1739884) or combination of several async streams into one (see [aiostream](https://pypi.org/project/aiostream/)). The (async) generator approach is really modular and flexible, which is not the case for the callback approach.